# UI app on Node.js and api using Django REST

Tags: angularjs, django, node.js, rest

I have found this amazing AngularJS based template that I would like to use, which currently is build to be launched as a Node.js application and then there is a ton of data that I have in a dozen tables that I am planning to wrap with a Django REST framework.

Eventually the UI application would communicate with the Django REST framework. Do you think this is a good idea. Or should I just stay on one of the frameworks? I would like to hear both pro's and con's from people with expertise on both the frameworks.